# Memory consumption in haskell using Int64

Tags: haskell, 64-bit, memory-consumption

The the problem is to find the last element. It works well Integer type. Overflow with Int type but when i try Int64 it seems that garbage collector stops working.

```
module Main (main) where
import Data.Int
import System.Environment

getNum :: Int -> Int64

merge [] s2 = s2
merge s1 [] = s1
merge (s1:s1s) (s2:s2s)
      | s1 < s2 = s1 : (merge s1s (s2:s2s))
      | s1 > s2 = s2 : (merge (s1:s1s) s2s)
      | otherwise = s1 : (merge s1s s2s)

scaleStreams scale = map $ (*) scale       

getNum n = s_3_56!!n
    where s_3_56 = 1:(merge (scaleStreams 2 s_3_56)
                     (merge (scaleStreams 3 s_3_56)
                     (scaleStreams 5 s_3_56 )))

main = do
    snum:_ <- getArgs
    putStrLn $ show $ getNum (read snum)
```

UPD. missed import Data.Int.
And 100,000,000 element needed. 
When using Int64 it just stops responding or stop to use processor.

Maybe i need some key for ghc so it could clean up elements i dont need.

These all is about benchmarking, so thats i need something more clear that Integer.

Comment: What error are you getting? Try importing `Data.Int` - `Int64` is not in the Prelude. Also, if you use Integer (which is in the Prelude!) you won't run into any overflow. I can, in GHCi, quickly compute that `getNum 200000` equals `4480327901140333639941336854183943340032000000000` :-)

Comment: Yes, use `Integer`, it's a good default.  Only go for some other type if `Integer` proves to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the downvotes? I don't think the asker being mistaken about what the problem was, or not possessing strong command of English should warrant downvotes ...

Comment: I think he's mistaken about what the problem was.  Using `Int64` causes overflow and the merge will go bonkers.

Answer (score 6):

From the size of the numbers, it's clear that you're going to overflow with `Int` or `Int64`. This will mess up the comparisons in `merge`.

Changing it to use the arbitrarily-sized `Integer`, we can observe that your algorithm appears to exhibit approximately linear time and space complexity.

```
*Main> :set +s
*Main> getNum 10
15
(0.05 secs, 15791376 bytes)
*Main> getNum 100
1600
(0.04 secs, 15805848 bytes)
*Main> getNum 1000
51840000
(0.05 secs, 16849584 bytes)
*Main> getNum 10000
288555831593533440
(0.10 secs, 26238720 bytes)
*Main> getNum 100000
290237644800000000000000000000000000000
(0.39 secs, 149698872 bytes)
*Main> getNum 1000000
519381797917090766274082018159448243742493816603938969600000000000000000000000000000
(3.57 secs, 1440858488 bytes)
*Main> getNum 10000000
16244249195502759967226308067328000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
(36.49 secs, 15318940632 bytes)
*Main> getNum 100000000
18140183964781799067475734441903054103752590419562119585784549199072397211943448001454797147212334274622985787416351057209969867746413217762757199393702760885526212114105820164278263467669252072928640885180135225440700708077201852574944496154785156250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
(398.26 secs, 173628505536 bytes)
```

The garbage collector appears to be working correctly as far as I can tell. The run with 100,000,000 allocates a total of 173GB of memory, but the highest peak I observed at any single time was about 900MB.

Comment: I just need to measure time with Int64 to be sure that data type is the same as in C# version of it, cuz i cant measure time when c# is using BigInteger and haskell Integer.

Comment: @rudzon: Well, then you need to test with smaller inputs, as overflows will prevent your program from working. Remember, the largest number that will fit in an `Int64` is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, so even `getNum 100000` goes way past that.

Comment: Thanks, but i dont care about overflow :P just want to measure calculation speed using Int64.

Comment: @rudzon You have to care about overflow since the comparison in merge will go totally wrong if you overflow.

Comment: @rudzon: My point is that the overflow does not only affect the result of your calculation, but that it also causes comparisons like `s1 < s2` to be thrown off when one of them overflows and goes negative, causing your program to follow different execution paths and possibly not even terminate. You cannot make a sensible speed measurement under such conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need the line

```
import Data.Int
```

in your code.